# Change language of button plus in kendo-grid-column in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, internationalization, kendo-grid

I am using kendo in Angular and I want to internationalize the "Expand details" message of the plus button. How could I do this? I am using the kendo-grid and kendo-grid-column element.

- Angular version: 8.2.14
- Kendo angular grid version: 4.7.2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `kendo-grid-messages` directive to set any text you want to appear instead of the default. In your case, add this inside your `kendo-grid` element template, like this:

```
<kendo-grid>
    <kendo-grid-messages detailExpand="Custom message">
    </kendo-grid-messages>
</kendo-grid>
```

You can read more about it in the documentation [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CustomMessagesComponent/#toc-detailexpand).